# Reading input file with additional separators in Python

Tags: python, syntax-error, file-read

```
lst = ['>CW500.8     \n', 'ATGCTATCATTA\n', '>CW500.9     \n', 'ATGCTATCATTA\n', '>CW500.10    \n', 'ATGCTATCATTT\n', '\n', '$$$\n', '\n', '>WT    \n', 'GTGCTATCATTA '] #Fastq formatted file
orgs = []
seqlist1 = []
seqstring = ""

for line in lst:
    if line.startswith(">"):
        if seqstring != "":
            seqlist1.append(seqstring) #makes the sequence a list
            seqstring = ""
        orgs.append(line.rstrip("\n")) #makes >indv's keys
    else:
        seqstring += line.rstrip("\n") #adds the seq string to the list
seqlist1.append(seqstring)  #must do this or your last line is lost

Output :  ['ATGCTATCATTA', 'ATGCTATCATTA', 'ATGCTATCATTT$$$', 'GTGCTATCATTA ']
```

I need to change the output such that the read that follows that '$$$' is appended into a new list. So I modified the above code:

```
orgs = []
seqlist1 = []
seqlist2 = []
seqstring = ""

for line in lst:
    if line.startswith(">"):
        if seqstring != "":
            seqlist1.append(seqstring) #makes the sequence a list
            seqstring = ""
    orgs.append(line.rstrip("\n")) #makes >indv's keys
    else:
        seqstring += line.rstrip("\n") #adds the seq string to the list   
    elif line.startswith("$$$"):
        seqlist2.append(seqstring)
seqlist1.append(seqstring)#must do this or your last line is lost
seqlist2.append(seqstring) 

print seqlist1
print seqlist2

Output:  File "/tmp/execpad-49ffac3cc5b6/source-49ffac3cc5b6", line 15
elif line.startswith("$$$"):
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Expected Output:
['ATGCTATCATTA', 'ATGCTATCATTA', 'ATGCTATCATTT']
['GTGCTATCATTA']
```

Can anyone explain to me where I am going wrong and how may I be able to further modify the code for the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You have an `elif` without a corresponding `if` preceding it. This is not permitted in Python syntax.

Comment: I have corrected for the same, keeping only if and elif. However, I still seem to be running to an error

Comment: @Biotechgeek - Then you have a different problem. Attempt to resolve it on your own first. If you are unable to resolve it after reading up on Python syntax and doing significant research, ask a question. This site is for specific questions and answers, not tutoring sessions - modifying your question in a way that invalidates existing answers removes the utility for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = ['>CW500.8     \n', 'ATGCTATCATTA\n', '>CW500.9     \n', 'ATGCTATCATTA\n', '>CW500.10    \n', 'ATGCTATCATTT\n', '\n', '$$$\n', '\n', '>WT    \n', 'GTGCTATCATTA '] #Fastq formatted file
new_list = []

def word_lister(list):
    for line in list:
        stripped = line.strip()
        replaced = stripped.replace(" ", "")
        if replaced.isalpha():
            new_list.append(replaced)
    # this is to print it
    for new in new_list:
        print(new)
    # this will return a array
    return new_list

word_lister(lst)
```

I just wrapped it in a function . It will take your list and will strip/replace spaces with nothing. Then check if it is a alphabet letter via `.isalpha()`. I also append the output to a new array for returning it, or you can just use the output printed.